can readLAS be used to read lidar from a URL or ftp site?
Is it possible to read from a url with readLAS or even with a catalog?
I am try to read lidar from the USGS lidar archive with lidR, but I am getting an error. I have tried a couple of approaches
  laz_url = "https://rockyweb.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Elevation/LPC/Projects/AK_GlacierBay_2019_B19/AK_GlacierBay_4_2019/LAZ/USGS_LPC_AK_GlacierBay_2019_B19_GB_00001.laz"

 #approach 1 - does not work
  test_con=url(laz_url, open="r")
  readLAS(test_con)
  close(test_con)

  #approach 2 - does not work
  readLAS(laz_url)


No, the code seems to explicitly test for files, so even trying a connection object won't work.
readLAS has these internal methods:
> lidR:::readLAS<hit tab for completion here>
lidR:::readLAS             lidR:::readLAS.LAScatalog  lidR:::readLAScatalog      
lidR:::readLAS.character   lidR:::readLAS.LAScluster  lidR:::readLASheader       

which eventually calls lidR:::assert_all_are_existing_files:
function (x) 
{
    x. <- lazyeval::expr_text(x)
    if (!all(file.exists(x))) 
        stop(glue::glue("File does not exist."), call. = FALSE)
}

You probably need to use something like download.file to get it from a URL.
